# How to get someones current location in Swift iOS Programming?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, gps, location

I'm trying to figure out how to get someones current location using SWIFT for a iOS app in XCODE.

I was following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkVI3njOlqU&nohtml5=False), but for some reason my code isn't working. I think it's because I am using a more updated Xcode versioning. For some reason my delegate has different parameters and I'm not sure why, but when I build my program it isn't even asking me if I want to allow location services at all.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // GPS STUFF
    // UPDATE LOCATION
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!) { (placemarks, ErrorType) -> Void in
            if(ErrorType != nil)
            {
                print("Error: " + ErrorType!.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }

            if(placemarks?.count > 0)
            {
                let pm = placemarks![0] ;
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm);
            }
        }
    }

    // STOP UPDATING LOCATION
    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
    {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
        print(placemark.locality);
        print(placemark.postalCode);
        print(placemark.administrativeArea);
        print(placemark.country);
    }
```

Also, in info.plist I also added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Info.plist`, add this:

[image]

or you can add like this in your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To get current location</string>
```

This will ask you to allow location services.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either.

Comment: Anything look like it could be wrong in my locationManager function?

Comment: You forgot to fill mapView.showsUserLocation = true in your viewDidLoad, let try this.

Comment: Check my update answer !!

Comment: Did you do the same as the tutorial? Please do carefully again.

Comment: Yes, I'm not even using mapView, so I have no clue what you're alluding to.

Comment: You are correct, I wasn't putting the right thing in my info,plist

Comment: Oh, man =.=. Glad it help you :)